# Re-rolling secured red/yellow dice in Elder Sign?

Tags: elder-sign, dice

It's clear from the rules that any player can use the red/yellow dice secured by a spell during their turn for resolving a task without using an Add red/yellow die Cards' effects. The rule also says, any player can use dice secured by a spell during their turn for use in a Roll - does that mean that, in case a red/yellow was secured by a spell before my turn starts, I may add the special die/dice into my dice pool and use them in my roll WITHOUT using the Add red/yellow die Cards' effects?
Thank You for any help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The [latest copy](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05_ES_Revised_Rulebook.pdf) of the rules is actually much clearer than the version that came in my set. Here's the quote, with the same emphasis as the rulebook, but parenthetical bits removed:

> When a die is secured on a Spell card, it remains there until **any**
>   player chooses to use it to complete a task, removes it from the spell
>   to roll it, or until another
>   effect locks that die. For spells that
>   secure multiple dice, the player may remove dice from it one at a time
>   or all at once.